# airflow DAG run: unpickling with dill gives NameError: name 'timedelta' is not defined

Tags: airflow, virtualenv, pickle, dill

I have a simple DAG (with `render_template_as_native_obj` option enabled). I'm trying to pass a `{{ dag_run }}` to a `PythonVirtualenvOperator`, but when it starts to execute it fails with `NameError: name 'timedelta' is not defined` error.

I'm trying to use it on `Python 3.11`, `airflow==2.7.3` and `dill==0.3.7`.
How can I cope with this error?

Here's my DAG:

```
import datetime
from pathlib import Path
import airflow
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator, PythonVirtualenvOperator
import dill


dag = DAG(
    dag_id='strange_pickling_error_dag',
    schedule_interval='0 5 * * 1',
    start_date=datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1),
    catchup=False,
    render_template_as_native_obj=True,
)


context = {"ts": "{{ ts }}", "dag_run": "{{ dag_run }}"}
op_args = [context, Path(__file__).parent.absolute()]


def make_foo(*args, **kwargs):
    print("---> making foo!")
    print("make foo(...): args")
    print(args)
    print("make foo(...): kwargs")
    print(kwargs)


make_foo_task = PythonVirtualenvOperator(
    task_id='make_foo',
    python_callable=make_foo,
    use_dill=True,
    system_site_packages=False,
    op_args=op_args,
    requirements=[f"dill=={dill.__version__}", f"apache-airflow=={airflow.__version__}"],
    dag=dag)
```

Here's the error:

```
[2023-11-06, 18:23:21 UTC] {process_utils.py:182} INFO - Executing cmd: /tmp/venvqse65m1b/bin/python /tmp/venvqse65m1b/script.py /tmp/venvqse65m1b/script.in /tmp/venvqse65m1b/script.out /tmp/venvqse65m1b/string_args.txt /tmp/venvqse65m1b/termination.log
[2023-11-06, 18:23:21 UTC] {process_utils.py:186} INFO - Output:
[2023-11-06, 18:23:21 UTC] {process_utils.py:190} INFO - Traceback (most recent call last):
[2023-11-06, 18:23:21 UTC] {process_utils.py:190} INFO -   File "/tmp/venvqse65m1b/script.py", line 17, in <module>
[2023-11-06, 18:23:21 UTC] {process_utils.py:190} INFO -     arg_dict = dill.load(file)
[2023-11-06, 18:23:21 UTC] {process_utils.py:190} INFO -                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[2023-11-06, 18:23:21 UTC] {process_utils.py:190} INFO -   File "/tmp/venvqse65m1b/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 287, in load
[2023-11-06, 18:23:21 UTC] {process_utils.py:190} INFO -     return Unpickler(file, ignore=ignore, **kwds).load()
[2023-11-06, 18:23:21 UTC] {process_utils.py:190} INFO -            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[2023-11-06, 18:23:21 UTC] {process_utils.py:190} INFO -   File "/tmp/venvqse65m1b/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 442, in load
[2023-11-06, 18:23:21 UTC] {process_utils.py:190} INFO -     obj = StockUnpickler.load(self)
[2023-11-06, 18:23:21 UTC] {process_utils.py:190} INFO -           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[2023-11-06, 18:23:21 UTC] {process_utils.py:190} INFO -   File "/home/felix/Projects/alfabank/fs_etl/venv_py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pendulum/tz/timezone.py", line 312, in __init__
[2023-11-06, 18:23:21 UTC] {process_utils.py:190} INFO -     self._utcoffset = timedelta(seconds=offset)
[2023-11-06, 18:23:21 UTC] {process_utils.py:190} INFO -                       ^^^^^^^^^
[2023-11-06, 18:23:21 UTC] {process_utils.py:190} INFO - NameError: name 'timedelta' is not defined
[2023-11-06, 18:23:22 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1937} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/felix/Projects/alfabank/fs_etl/venv_py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 395, in execute
    return super().execute(context=serializable_context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/felix/Projects/alfabank/fs_etl/venv_py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 192, in execute
    return_value = self.execute_callable()
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/felix/Projects/alfabank/fs_etl/venv_py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 609, in execute_callable
    result = self._execute_python_callable_in_subprocess(python_path, tmp_path)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/felix/Projects/alfabank/fs_etl/venv_py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 446, in _execute_python_callable_in_subprocess
    execute_in_subprocess(
  File "/home/felix/Projects/alfabank/fs_etl/venv_py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/utils/process_utils.py", line 171, in execute_in_subprocess
    execute_in_subprocess_with_kwargs(cmd, cwd=cwd)
  File "/home/felix/Projects/alfabank/fs_etl/venv_py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/utils/process_utils.py", line 194, in execute_in_subprocess_with_kwargs
    raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(exit_code, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/tmp/venvqse65m1b/bin/python', '/tmp/venvqse65m1b/script.py', '/tmp/venvqse65m1b/script.in', '/tmp/venvqse65m1b/script.out', '/tmp/venvqse65m1b/string_args.txt', '/tmp/venvqse65m1b/termination.log']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Comment: It seems like something to do with the pendulum module. can you specify an older & also the latest release versions to test if this error is reproducible across different versions?

Comment: Well, I've tried pendulum 2.0.0 and 2.1.2 -- and with both of them I get the same error.

Comment: @Felix could you please explain why you are using `PythonVirtualenvOperator` instead of `PythonOperator`? `airflow` + `dill` already installed.

Comment: @DanilaGanchar, we have to use `PythonVirtualenvOperator` operators because In different DAGs we have different (and sometimes conflicting) Python package dependency list.

Answer (score 1):

After some investigation i have found out that:

- this problem with `timedelta` occurs with `dill >= 3.6`. With `dill==0.3.5.1` it does not happen;
- this problem can be fixed by using `pendulum==3.0`, but it is not currently supported by `airflow` (there is already a PR: https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/34744 but it is not yet merged into master branch).

Comment: thanks for following up on this one!